# How to detect keypress

Tags: java, keyboard, key, user-input

I am using java and trying to write a simple sudo mouse recorder that will store the mouse position when the space key is pressed. The only key I need to detect is the space key (Although if another key is easier, that will work).

I need the whole mouse recorder to be written in java, but it is OK if the function for the keypress is in another language. And I will be runing this in Windows 7.

What is the simplest way to do what has been described? All of the methods I have found require at minimum 20 lines of code. This is OK, except I don't understand how to implement them. I have an example source below:

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MouseRecorder {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int slot = 0;
        int xLoc[10];
        int yLoc[10];

        while (slot <= 10)
        {
            if (keyPressed(KEY_SPACE)) //<<<<This obviously won't work, but I'm looking for the simplest way to code this
            {
                xLoc[slot] = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                yLoc[slot] = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
                slot++;
            }
        }

        //The mouse information can now be utilized
    }
}
```

Comment: `"All of the methods I have found require at minimum 20 lines of code."` -- what's bad about 20 lines of code? What is your purpose in compressing the code? You need a Swing GUI, and that GUI to have focus for Swing to work in this situation.

Comment: How to Use Key Bindings? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: It smells like to me that you might want a system-wide key logger that only responds to one key press, and that doesn't need a GUI. If this is so, then your best solution is to **not** use Java to create your application but to use a tool that can get closer to the OS. AutoIt comes to mind if this is for a Windows project. Please define your needs better.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: What's bad about 20 lines of code is that It makes things much more complex and if possible would be much more readable with one to five lines.

And yes, you are correct, I dont want a gui, if I can avoid it.

Comment: @RandomPerson323: because it is impossible to do if you are trying to do this with Swing code in 5 lines. Period. I'd like to have a pony too, but it's just not going to happen. As per my comment above this one, you're going to have to define your problem space a bit better to get better help.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: OK, thank you for your help; that is the reason I asked it: to see if it is possible.

Comment: Again, please **define your requirements**. What **exactly** are you trying to do? Use a key as a hot-key? What? What is your platform? Windows? Mac? Unix? Multiple platforms?

Comment: I described this in the post, **"store the mouse position when the space key is pressed"**. For example, your mouse is over the exact pixel: (12, 15) and if you press the space key, those values are stored in the array. And how should the platform affect this code (this is a sincere question because I thought java was compatible with almost everything for Linux/Unix, Mac, and Windows...)

Comment: @RandomPerson323 The 20 lines can be hidden away in some other class/method and then you'll never need to worry about them again

Comment: @Richard Tingle: This would actually work, now I just need to figure out how to use key bindings/listeners because I do not understand them.

Comment: @RandomPerson323 Indeed, all programs would look hideous if written as a single method; break them down. Good luck, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) should take you through it and ask annother question if you run into difficulties

Comment: @Richard Tingle: Thanks, I will attempt this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again your question is not clear since you have not addressed my comment:

> It smells like to me that you might want a system-wide key logger that only responds to one key press, and that doesn't need a GUI. If this is so, then your best solution is to not use Java to create your application but to use a tool that can get closer to the OS. AutoIt comes to mind if this is for a Windows project. Please define your needs better.

and this forces us to guess at the problem and its solution.

---

If you are interested in creating a Swing GUI, having it take focus, and have it listen to key events, then the solution is to do this:

- Create your Swing GUI and display it, leaving it as the active windowed application while your application is running.
- Using Key Bindings have it listen for space bar presses
- And then log the mouse location when the space bar is pressed.
- As noted, this will not be achievable in 5 lines of code, so put that idea to the side.

---

If on the other hand your desire is to not have a GUI but rather listen for hot-key presses while any and all applications are running, then

- The possible platforms used will be critical since your solution will require OS-specific code since creating a hot-key means having to create a keyboard handler routine, often in C, and doing this for each platform, and then linking it in to Java using JNI or JNA.
- Or as noted another way is to link your Java program with an OS specific utility program or script such as AutoIt.

---

If you need more specific help, then please clarify your question.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> Thank you for the answer, but as I have described above: "Changing languages is out of the question although it seems like that might be easier." and "I dont want a gui, if I can avoid it"

Then my second answer is what you're looking for. How adept are you at C/C++, JNI or JNA, and how good is your knowledge of operating system libraries? If you want a Java only solution, I would consider your requirements far above beginner or intermediate Java and into the realm of advanced -- or at least beyond my abilities at the moment, although I am sure that I could come up with some solutions after several days to a week or two of study.

... or consider getting rid of your "changing languages" requirement and instead allow at least meshing Java together with a scripting utility, like AutoIt. That could allow creation of solutions in a shorter period of time, at least for me. A limitation though is that these would be platform specific solutions. What is your purpose behind all of this? Could this be an XY problem in disguise?

---

**Edit 2**

I decided to try to solve this with a small AutoIt utility that I meshed with Java, and this is what I came up with.

My AutoIt program is called CaptureHotKey.au3, and it is compiled to an exe before use:

```
$key = $CmdLine[1]

HotKeySet($key, "hotKeyFunction")

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func hotKeyFunction()
    ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
EndFunc
```

There's not much to it. All it does is set a hot-key from the first command line parameter, provides an endless while loop so that it will continue to run, and a hotkey function that is quite simple and only sends a carriage-return/line-feed to the console (which will be the standard output).

---

Then a Java class to help interact with this. It uses SwingPropertyLanguageSupport to allow addition of PropertyChangeListeners that respond on the Swing thread (in case I want to use this with a GUI).

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class CaptureHotKey implements Runnable {
   public static final String HOT_KEY = "hot key";
   private String hotKey;
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
         this);
   private Scanner scanner;
   private CaptureHotKeyFromAutoIt capture;

   public CaptureHotKey(final String hotKey) throws IOException {
      this.hotKey = hotKey;     
      capture = new CaptureHotKeyFromAutoIt(hotKey);
      scanner = new Scanner(capture.getReadable());
   }

   public void startCapturing() {
      new Thread(this).start();
   }

   public void exit() {
      if (capture != null) {
         capture.exit();  
      }
      if (scanner != null) {
         scanner.close();
      }
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public String getHotKey() {
      return hotKey;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      while (scanner != null && scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         scanner.nextLine();
         pcSupport.firePropertyChange(HOT_KEY, true, false);
      }
   }

   private static class CaptureHotKeyFromAutoIt {
      public static final String AUTO_IT_APP_PATH = "CaptureHotKey.exe";

      private Process process = null;
      private ProcessBuilder pb;

      public CaptureHotKeyFromAutoIt(String hotKey) throws IOException {
         List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();
         cmdList.add(AUTO_IT_APP_PATH);
         cmdList.add(hotKey);
         pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
         pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
         process = pb.start();
      }

      public void exit() {
         if (process != null) {
            process.destroy();
         }
      }

      public Readable getReadable() {
         if (process != null) {
            return new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
         }
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

---

Finally a Java class to test this set up:;

This adds a PropertyChangeListener to the class above to  allow it to be notified if the   hot-key is pressed:

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaptureHotKeyTest {
   public static final String CTRL_R = "^r"; // "{SPACE}" works for spacebar
   private static final String EXIT = "exit";
   private CaptureHotKey capture;

   public CaptureHotKeyTest() {
      try {
         capture = new CaptureHotKey(CTRL_R);
         capture.addPropertyChangeListener(new HotKeyPropertyChngListener());
         capture.startCapturing();

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Press control-r to get mouse position.");
         System.out.println("Type \"exit\" to exit program");
         while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT)) {
               scan.close();
               capture.exit();
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }      
   }

   private class HotKeyPropertyChngListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(CaptureHotKey.HOT_KEY)) {
            System.out.println("hot key pressed");

            PointerInfo pointerInfo = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            System.out.println("Mouse: " + pointerInfo.getLocation());
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new CaptureHotKeyTest();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I have described above: **"Changing languages is out of the question although it seems like that might be easier."** and **"I dont want a gui, if I can avoid it"**

Comment: Acually, thinking about it, I can be more specific. I edited the main post about the language requirements.

Comment: I finally might be getting on to something (Although its Windows Specific, I beleive): http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Comment: @RandomPerson323: yep, that could work. As you see, the solution requires JNI to merge in CPP code. Again, what are your plans for using this program? And yes, it is most definitely Windows specific. No solution can be OS-agnostic as far as I know.

Comment: My plans are to create my own mouse listener specified for my needs (And now that I have figured out how to use the daemon/hook, fun is just around the corner xD).

Comment: @RandomPerson323: Indeed that does sound like fun. Again, good luck and much success!

Comment: @RandomPerson323: for what it's worth, I've posted my AutoIt solution above.

Answer (score -1):

You should use KeyListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html
It works fine with Swing

Comment: Please read the entire question and all the comments. This will not work for the original poster's purposes. Also, in situations where you would use a KeyListener from within a Swing application, it is almost always better to use Key Bindings as has been discussed many times on this site.